# How to fix outdated internal index table in an addon

Tags: python, add-on, weight-painting

I downloaded Blur Weights addon, since it was made for blender 2.63 it is giving an error in blender 2.74 when trying to use it.

[image]

[image]

Why does this error happens and how can it be fixed to make outdated addons to work with newer versions of blender?

Addon [link](https://github.com/assumptionsoup/Blur-Weights)

Comment: https://github.com/assumptionsoup/Blur-Weights/issues/1 someone has already offered a fix in the addon's issue tracker, you can apply the fix locally. or try the fork: https://github.com/zeffii/Blur-Weights

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was added to speed up scripts. The [Blender 2.73 release notes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.73/Addons) mention it and reference [the commit](https://developer.blender.org/rB785b90d7efd0) that introduced it (in the Python API section)

A backwards compatible solution is the following addition before any code that accesses bm.verts / bm.edges / bm.faces indices explicitly. For clarity, that means if an addon has any code like this:

```
bm.verts[i]
bm.edges[i]
bm.faces[i]
```

Then preceding it must be a call to `ensure_lookup_table`. Often you'll only need to do one such call, and you'll want to stick it outside of any tight loops if possible.

```
if hasattr(bm.verts, "ensure_lookup_table"): 
    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
    # only if you need to:
    # bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()   
    # bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
```

If you add new *verts / edges / faces* to the bm, and then subsequently do an indexed lookup you might find that you need to call `ensure_lookup_table` again.